# Access denied or format unknown on field in Services Views

Tags: views, services

Installed the following modules in Drupal 7

- Services
- Services Views

When creating new services view, I am facing the following issue.

nid and title fields shown correctly, but other fields including body and custom fields showing the following error. **"Access denied or format unknown on field."**

The preview shows as below:

```
array (
  0 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'nid' => '47',
     'title' => 'World Cup Stadiums',
     'publish_date' => 
    array (
      'error' => 'Access denied or format unknown on field.',
    ),
  )),
  1 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'nid' => '49',
     'title' => 'Ladies Fencing Tournament 2014',
     'publish_date' => 
    array (
      'error' => 'Access denied or format unknown on field.',
    ),
  )),
  2 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'nid' => '48',
     'title' => 'FIfa World Cup',
     'publish_date' => 
    array (
      'error' => 'Access denied or format unknown on field.',
    ),
  )),
  3 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'nid' => '46',
     'title' => 'Fifa World Cup Title',
     'publish_date' => 
    array (
      'error' => 'Access denied or format unknown on field.',
    ),
  )),
)
```

Comment: Similar problem using Commerce Kickstart , Services & Services Views. I can't display any Commerce products , except for the title & nid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to uncheck the "Use field template" inside the "STYLE SETTINGS" of your 'publish_date' field.